Structure of the SAM template is invalid. All 'Resources' must be Objects
Hi I'm getting an error:
Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Structure of the SAM template is invalid. All 'Resources' must be Objects. If you're using YAML, this may be an indentation issue. 
When trying to deploy a cloudformation template that creates an aurora database within an exisiting vpc with a password roatation lambda.
When running the cloudofmration, there is an error that indicates that there is an issue with the Serverless application indentation.
This is the template:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: 
  - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
  - AWS::LanguageExtensions

Description: Deploys an Aurora cluster into an existing VPC

Parameters:
  EnvironmentName:
    Description: An environment name that will be prefixed.

    Type: String
    Default: dev
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - test
      - staging
      - prod
    
  DBClusterType:
    Description: Aurora Cluster Type
    Type: String
    Default: AuroraClusterPostgreSQL
    AllowedValues:
      - AuroraClusterPostgreSQL
  
  PropertiesUrl:
    Type: String
    Description: Name of bucket in which the environment-specific constants are stored
    Default: s3://devops-deploy-us-east-1/services/test.yaml
  
  MapName:
    Type: String
    Description: Configuration MapName.
    Default: Properties

Mappings:
  "Fn::Transform":
    Name: "AWS::Include"
    Parameters:
      Location: !Ref PropertiesUrl

Conditions:
  CreateSecondDBInstance: !Equals [!FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, TwoInstancesInCluster ], 'true']

Resources:
  
  # ################################################  Security Group  ##########################################
  
  DBSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join
        - "-"
        - - !Ref EnvironmentName
          - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ]
          - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
          - "sg"
      GroupDescription: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBPort ]
          ToPort: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBPort ]
          CidrIp: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/vpc/cidr:1}}'
          Description: 'VPC Access to DataBase'
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBPort ]
          ToPort: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBPort ]
          SourceSecurityGroupId: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/eks/cluster-nodes-security-group-id:1}}'
          Description: Allows access to Aurora from EKS Node Groups
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBPort ]
          ToPort: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBPort ]
          CidrIp: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/office-network-cidr:1}}'
          Description: Allows access to Aurora
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBPort ]
          ToPort: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBPort ]
          CidrIp: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/vpn-network-cidr:1}}'
          Description: Allows access to Aurora from VPN CIDR
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          FromPort: -1
          ToPort: -1
          IpProtocol: '-1'
      VpcId: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/vpc/id:1}}'
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join
            - "-"
            - - !Ref EnvironmentName
              - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ]
              - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
              - "sg"
        - Key: Product
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Product ]
        - Key: Service
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Service ]
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
  
  DBSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 0
      ToPort: 65535
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref DBSecurityGroup
      Description: 'Self Reference'
  
  # ######################################################  Subnet Group  ##########################################
  
  DBSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Join
        - "-"
        - - !Ref EnvironmentName
          - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ]
          - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
          - "subnet-group"
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: "Database Subnet Group"
      SubnetIds:
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/vpc/private-db-subnet-a-id:1}}'
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/vpc/private-db-subnet-b-id:1}}'
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/vpc/private-db-subnet-c-id:1}}'
      Tags:
        - Key: Product
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Product ]
        - Key: Service
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Service ]
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
  
  ################################################# Aurora  #############################################
  
  DBCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Snapshot
    Properties:
      Engine: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
      EngineVersion: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngineVersion ]
      DatabaseName: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DatabaseName ]
      MasterUsername: !Join ['', ['{', '{', 'resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref DBMasterSecret, ':SecretString:username', '}', '}' ]]
      MasterUserPassword: !Join ['', ['{' ,'{', 'resolve:secretsmanager:', !Ref DBMasterSecret, ':SecretString:password', '}', '}' ]]
      Port: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBPort ]
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Join
        - "-"
        - - !Ref EnvironmentName
          - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ]
          - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
      #    DBClusterParameterGroupName: !Ref DBClusterParameterGroup
      #DBClusterParameterGroupName: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBClusterParameterGroupName ]
      BackupRetentionPeriod: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, BackupRetentionPeriod]
      PreferredBackupWindow: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, PreferredBackupWindow ]
      PreferredMaintenanceWindow: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, PreferredMaintenanceWindow ]
      DeletionProtection: false
      StorageEncrypted: true
      EnableHttpEndpoint: true
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref DBSecurityGroup
      EnableCloudwatchLogsExports:
        - audit
        - error
        - general
      Tags:
        - Key: Product
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Product ]
        - Key: Service
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Service ]
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  DBFirstInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      #      CopyTagsToSnapshot: true
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ '0', { Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region' } ]
      DBInstanceClass: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBInstanceClass ]
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref DBCluster
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Join [ '-', [ !Ref DBCluster, !Select [ '0', { Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region' } ]]]
      Engine: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
      EngineVersion: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngineVersion ]
      AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, AutoMinorVersionUpgrade ]
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
      PubliclyAccessible: false
      EnablePerformanceInsights: false
      #PerformanceInsightsRetentionPeriod: 7
      Tags:
        - Key: Product
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Product ]
        - Key: Service
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Service ]
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  DBSecondInstance:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Condition: CreateSecondDBInstance
    DependsOn:
      - DBFirstInstance
    Properties:
      #      CopyTagsToSnapshot: true
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [ '1', { Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region' } ]
      DBInstanceClass: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBInstanceClass ]
      DBClusterIdentifier: !Ref DBCluster
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Join ['-', [ !Ref DBCluster, !Select [ '1', { Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region' } ]]]
      Engine: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
      EngineVersion: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngineVersion ]
      AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, AutoMinorVersionUpgrade ]
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref DBSubnetGroup
      PubliclyAccessible: false
      EnablePerformanceInsights: false
      #PerformanceInsightsRetentionPeriod: 7
      Tags:
        - Key: Product
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Product ]
        - Key: Service
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Service ]
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
  
  # ################################# Cluster Parameter Group ##########################################
  
  # DBClusterParameterGroup:
  #   Type: AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup
  #   Properties:
  #     Description: DB Cluster Parameter Group
  #     Family: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBFamily ]
  #     Parameters:
  #       time_zone: UTC
  #     Tags:
  #       - Key: Name
  #         Value: !Join
  #          - "-"
  #          - - !Sub ${EnvironmentName}
  #            - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ]
  #            - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
  #            - "parameter-group"
  #       - Key: Product
  #         Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Product ]
  #       - Key: Service
  #         Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Service ]
  #       - Key: Environment
  #         Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
  
  # ###################################################### Route 53 ##########################################
  
#  DBEndpointRoute53:
#    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
#    Properties:
#      HostedZoneName: !Join
#        - "."
#        - - !Ref EnvironmentName
#          - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/route53/internal-domain-private-hosted-zone-name:1}}'
#          - ""
#      Comment: Services DB DataBase DNS name.
#      Name: !Join
#        - "."
#        - - !Ref DBCluster
#          - !Ref EnvironmentName
#          - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/route53/internal-domain-private-hosted-zone-name:1}}'
#          - ""
#      Type: CNAME
#      TTL: 300
#      ResourceRecords:
#        - !GetAtt DBCluster.Endpoint.Address
#
  
  # ############################################# Event Subscription ##########################################

  DBClusterEventSubscription:
    Type: AWS::RDS::EventSubscription
    Properties:
      EventCategories:
        - failover
        - failure
        - notification
      SnsTopicArn: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      SourceIds: [ !Ref DBCluster ]
      SourceType: db-cluster

  FirstDBInstanceEventSubscription:
    Type: AWS::RDS::EventSubscription
    Properties:
      EventCategories:
        - failover
        - availability
        - deletion
        - low storage
        - read replica
        - recovery
        - restoration
        - failure
        - notification
      SnsTopicArn: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      SourceIds:
        - !Ref DBFirstInstance
      SourceType: db-instance

  SecondDBInstanceEventSubscription:
    Condition: CreateSecondDBInstance
    Type: AWS::RDS::EventSubscription
    Properties:
      EventCategories:
        - failover
        - availability
        - deletion
        - low storage
        - read replica
        - recovery
        - restoration
        - failure
        - notification
      SnsTopicArn: !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      SourceIds:
        - !Ref DBSecondInstance
      SourceType: db-instance
  
  # ********************** Master Username ************************
  
  #aws secretsmanager delete-secret --secret-id <secrets-arn> --force-delete-without-recovery --profile dev
  
  DBMasterSecret:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    # DeletionPolicy: Retain
    UpdateReplacePolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      Name: !Join
        - "-"
        - - !Ref EnvironmentName
          - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ]
          - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
          - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, MasterUsername ]
      Description: !Join
        - "-"
        - - "DB 'admin' User Secret"
          - !Ref EnvironmentName
          - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ]
          - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: !Join
          - ''
          - - '{"username": "'
            - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, MasterUsername ]
            - '", "ssl": "true", "dbname": ""}'
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
        ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\'
        #PasswordLength: 16
      Tags:
        - Key: Product
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Product ]
        - Key: Service
          Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Service ]
        - Key: Environment
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentName

  DBMasterSecretClusterAttachment:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::SecretTargetAttachment
    Properties:
      SecretId: !Ref DBMasterSecret
      TargetId: !Ref DBCluster
      TargetType: AWS::RDS::DBCluster

  DBMasterSecretRotationSchedule:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::RotationSchedule
    DependsOn: DBMasterSecretClusterAttachment
    Properties:
      SecretId: !Ref DBMasterSecret
      RotateImmediatelyOnUpdate: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, RotateImmediatelyOnUpdate ]
      RotationLambdaARN: !GetAtt SecretsManagerRotationServerlessApp.Outputs.RotationLambdaARN
      RotationRules:
        AutomaticallyAfterDays: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, PasswordRotationDays ]

  SecretsManagerRotationServerlessApp:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Application
    Properties:
      Location:
        ApplicationId: 'arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:297356227824:applications/SecretsManagerRDSPostgreSQLRotationMultiUser'
        SemanticVersion: 1.1.464
      Parameters:
        endpoint: !Sub 'https://secretsmanager.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com'
        functionName: !Join
          - "-"
          - - !Ref EnvironmentName
            - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ]
            - secret-manager-rotation-lambda
        vpcSecurityGroupIds: !Ref DBSecurityGroup
        vpcSubnetIds: !Join
          - ","
          - - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/vpc/private-db-subnet-a-id:1}}'
            - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/vpc/private-db-subnet-b-id:1}}'
            - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/vpc/private-db-subnet-c-id:1}}'
  #  ******************* App Username ************************

  Fn::ForEach::DBAppSecrets:
    - Service
    - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, Services]
    - 'dbAppSecret${Service}':
        Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
        Properties:
          Name: !Join
            - "-"
            - - !Ref EnvironmentName
              - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ]
              - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
              - ${Service}
          Description: !Join
            - "-"
            - - "DB User Secret for Service ${Service}"
              - !Ref EnvironmentName
              - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ]
              - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DBEngine ]
          GenerateSecretString:
            SecretStringTemplate: !Join
              - ''
              - - '{"username": "'
                - ${Service}
                - '", "ssl": "true", "masterarn": "'
                - !Ref DBMasterSecret
                - '", "dbname": ""}'
            GenerateStringKey: "password"
            ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\'
            #PasswordLength: 16
          Tags:
            - Key: Product
              Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Product ]
            - Key: Service
              Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Service ]
            - Key: Environment
              Value: !Ref EnvironmentName
        DependsOn:
          - DBMasterSecret


  Fn::ForEach::SecretTargetAttachment:
    - Service
    - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, Services]
    - 'secretTargetAttachment${Service}':
        Type: AWS::SecretsManager::SecretTargetAttachment
        Properties:
          SecretId: !Sub 'dbAppSecret${Service}'
          TargetId: !Ref DBCluster
          TargetType: AWS::RDS::DBCluster

  Fn::ForEach::RotationSchedule:
    - Service
    - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, Services]
    - 'rotationSchedule${Service}':
        Type: AWS::SecretsManager::RotationSchedule
        DependsOn: !Sub 'secretTargetAttachment${Service}'
        Properties:
          SecretId: !Sub 'dbAppSecret${Service}'
          RotationLambdaARN: !GetAtt SecretsManagerRotationServerlessApp.Outputs.RotationLambdaARN
          RotationRules:
            AutomaticallyAfterDays: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, PasswordRotationDays ]


  #  ******************* Alarms  ************************

  AlarmAuroraDbDeadlocksClusterMinor:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref EnvironmentName, !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ], "DBDeadlocks-alarm" ]]
      MetricName: Deadlocks
      Namespace: AWS/RDS
      Dimensions:
        - Name: DBClusterIdentifier
          Value: !Ref DBCluster
      AlarmDescription: !Sub "ENV : ${EnvironmentName}
        ResourceMetric : Deadlocks.
        Effect : Aurora deadlocks for DB instance threshold.
        Reason : There is deadlock in DB
        Severity : A minor alarm is raised when having even one deadlock in the DB. File an issue for developers to investigate the reason behind this failure.
        Priority of the issue created is P3."
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: 0
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      DatapointsToAlarm: 1
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      Period: 300
      AlarmActions:
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      OKActions:
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      TreatMissingData: ignore

  AlarmAuroraDbConnectionsClusterMajor:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref EnvironmentName, !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ], "DBConnections-alarm" ]]
      MetricName: DatabaseConnections
      Namespace: AWS/RDS
      Dimensions:
        - Name: DBClusterIdentifier
          Value: !Ref DBCluster
      AlarmDescription: !Sub "ENV : ${EnvironmentName}
        ResourceMetric : DatabaseConnections.
        Effect : DB instance. The current number of connections to an DB instance. The max connection to the DB is 1000
        Reason : High connection usage more than 80%
        Severity : A major alarm raises when the number of connections exceeds 800. File an issue for developers to investigate the reason behind this failure.
        Priority of the issue created is P2."
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: 800
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      DatapointsToAlarm: 1
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      Period: 300
      AlarmActions:
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      OKActions:
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      TreatMissingData: ignore

  AlarmAuroraFreeableMemoryClusterMajor:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref EnvironmentName, !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ], "FreeableMemory-alarm" ]]
      MetricName: FreeableMemory
      Namespace: AWS/RDS
      Dimensions:
        - Name: DBClusterIdentifier
          Value: !Ref DBCluster
      AlarmDescription: !Sub "ENV : ${EnvironmentName}
        ResourceMetric : FreeableMemory.
        Effect : DB instance, The amount of available random access memory. Freeable memory is low (1GB or lower). The amount of free memory available on the host.
          This is derived from the RAM, buffers, and cache that the OS reports as freeable.
          Monitor the freeable memory (FreeableMemory) metric to determine if your DB cluster is running out of available memory
        Reason : High memory usage.
        Severity : A major alarm that raises when Freeable memory is low 1GB. File an issue for developers to investigate the reason behind this failure.
        Priority of the issue created is P2."
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: 1000000000
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      DatapointsToAlarm: 1
      ComparisonOperator: LessThanOrEqualToThreshold
      Period: 300
      AlarmActions:
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      OKActions:
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      TreatMissingData: ignore

  AlarmAuroraFreeLocalStorageClusterMajor:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref EnvironmentName, !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ], "FreeLocalStorage-alarm" ]]
      MetricName: FreeLocalStorage
      Namespace: AWS/RDS
      Dimensions:
        - Name: DBClusterIdentifier
          Value: !Ref DBCluster
      AlarmDescription: !Sub "ENV : ${EnvironmentName}
        ResourceMetric : FreeLocalStorage .
        Effect : DB instance, Free local storage for cluster breaches threshold.
        Reason : High storage usage.
        Severity : A major alarm is raised when the free local storage of the cluster is lower than 450MB. File an issue for developers
          to investigate the reason behind this failure.
        Priority of the issue created is P2."
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: 450000000
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      DatapointsToAlarm: 1
      ComparisonOperator: LessThanOrEqualToThreshold
      Period: 300
      AlarmActions:
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      OKActions:
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      TreatMissingData: ignore

  AlarmAuroraCpuUtilizationClusterMajor:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmName: !Join [ "-", [ !Ref EnvironmentName, !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, ClusterName ], "CPUUtilization-alarm" ]]
      MetricName: CPUUtilization
      Namespace: AWS/RDS
      Dimensions:
        - Name: DBClusterIdentifier
          Value: !Ref DBCluster
      AlarmDescription: !Sub "ENV : ${EnvironmentName}
        ResourceMetric : CPUUtilization.
        Effect : DB instance, The percentage of CPU used by an DB instance.
        Reason : High cpu usage.
        Severity : Major alarm that raises when the percentage of CPU used by DB is higher than 80%. File an issue for
          developers to investigate the reason behind this failure.
        Priority of the issue created is P2."
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: 80
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      DatapointsToAlarm: 1
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold
      Period: 300
      AlarmActions:
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      OKActions:
        - !Sub '{{resolve:ssm:/${EnvironmentName}/aws/sns/major-alert-topic:1}}'
      TreatMissingData: ignore

  DBMasterSecretArnParameter:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub /${EnvironmentName}/aws/secret/${DBClusterType}/admin
      Type: String
      Value: !Ref DBMasterSecret
      Description: SSM Parameter for Aurora DB Secret Arn
      Tags:
        Product: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Product ]
        Service: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Service ]
        Environment: !Ref EnvironmentName

  Fn::ForEach::DBAppSecretsParam:
    - Service
    - !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, Services]
    - 'dbAppSecretParamArn${Service}':
        Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
        Properties:
          Name: !Sub /${EnvironmentName}/aws/secret/${Service}-app
          Type: String
          Value: !Sub 'dbAppSecret${Service}'
          Description: SSM Parameter for Aurora DB Secret Arn
          Tags:
            Product: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Product ]
            Service: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, Tags, Service ]
            Environment: !Ref EnvironmentName

Outputs:
  DBWriterEndpoint:
    Description: Services Aurora DB DataBase Writer Endpoint URL
    Value: !GetAtt DBFirstInstance.Endpoint.Address
    
  DBReaderEndpoint:
    Condition: CreateSecondDBInstance
    Description: Services Aurora DB DataBase Reader Endpoint URL
    Value: !GetAtt DBSecondInstance.Endpoint.Address
    
  DBName:
    Description: Services Aurora DB DataBase Name
    Value: !FindInMap [ !Ref MapName, !Ref DBClusterType, DatabaseName ]
    
  DBVpcSecurityGroupId:
    Description: Services Aurora DB DataBase VPC Security Group ID
    Value: !GetAtt DBSecurityGroup.GroupId
    
  DBMasterSecretArn:
    Value: !Ref DBMasterSecret
    Description: SSM Parameter for Aurora DB Master Secret Arn
  

I don't see any indentation issues within the Serverless Applicaiton. What is the issue?
